# Find limit of Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\dfrac{\sqrt[n]{a}+\sqrt[n]{b}+\sqrt[n]{c}}{3})^n$. I think the result is $\sqrt[3]{abc}$. And
I have result $\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\sqrt[n]{a}-1)=\ln{a}$. But I can't use it. Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Show your own effort to crack this. It'd be a good idea to say something more about what exactly $\;a,b,c,\;$ are, too...

Comment: Read about it: [Generalized mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean). In this case, $\frac{1}{n}\to 0$ so the result should be the geometric mean. Now try to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a generalization :

Let $ p\in\mathbb{N}^{*} $, and $ a_{1}, \cdots, a_{p}\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^{*} $, we have :\begin{aligned}\left(\frac{1}{p}\sum_{k=1}^{p}{\sqrt[n]{a_{k}}}\right)^{n}&=\operatorname{e}^{n\ln{\left(\frac{1}{p}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{p}{\sqrt[n]{a_{k}}}\right)}}\\ &=\exp{\left(\frac{n}{p}\sum_{k=1}^{p}{\left(\sqrt[n]{a_{k}}-1\right)}\times\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{1}{p}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{p}{\sqrt[n]{a_{k}}}\right)}}{\frac{1}{p}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{p}{\sqrt[n]{a_{k}}}-1}\right)}\\ &=\exp{\left(\frac{1}{p}\sum_{k=1}^{p}{\ln{a_{k}}\frac{\operatorname{e}^{\frac{\ln{a_{k}}}{n}}-1}{\frac{\ln{a_{k}}}{n}}}\times\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{1}{p}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{p}{\sqrt[n]{a_{k}}}\right)}}{\frac{1}{p}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{p}{\sqrt[n]{a_{k}}}-1}\right)}\\ &\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\exp{\left(\frac{1}{p}\sum_{k=1}^{p}{\ln{a_{k}}}\right)}=\left(\prod_{k=1}^{p}{a_{k}}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\end{aligned}

$\textbf{Note :}$ We've used the fact that $ \lim\limits_{x\to 0}{\frac{\operatorname{e}^{x}-1}{x}}=1 $, and that $ \lim\limits_{x\to 1}{\frac{\ln{x}}{x-1}} = 1 $.